# Sql Server : Update query inside a procedure not working even after optimisation

Tags: sql, sql-server, non-clustered-index

I will try to explain the question in detail:

I am facing a weird situation in which my procedure stops *occassionaly* at an UPDATE query.
This happens rarely like 1 in 1000 records which is making me clueless.

Also, this issue is not happening in DEV, it's only happening in PROD.
PROD environment doesn't allow any query analysis not it allows me to fire any commands like DBCC etc.

The query looks like below -

```sql
        CREATE proc [dbo].[Usp_SaveTaskSME]                                        
    (                                        
     @taskDlaIdSelected int                                     
    )                                        
    As                                        
    Begin        
     if exists(Select 1 from TaskDla where TaskDLAId = @taskDlaIdSelected)        
      Begin        
          
     declare @RequestId int, @taskid int, @submissionid int      
     select @RequestId = RequestId, @TaskId = TaskId, @submissionid = SubmissionFileId  from SubmissionFileData where TaskDLAId = @taskDlaIdSelected      
          
     -------- Mod#1 start    -------- **WORKS FINE  **
     Update Task      
     Set TaskStatusId = 1      
     Where TaskId = (Select TaskId from TaskDLA Where TaskDlaId = @taskDlaIdSelected)      
     -------- Mod#1 Ends      
          
     -- MOD #2 : log history of submission file update  --- **WORKS FINE**    
     insert into [dbo].[RequestHistory]        
      ([RequestId],[StatusId],[Description],[StatusChangeBy],[StatusChangeDate],[UpdateType])        
     values        
      (@RequestId, 1, 'TaskId #' + cast(@taskid as varchar) + ' set to In Progress', 'usp_SaveTaskSME', Getdate(), 'In Progress')      
          
     ---- Mod#3 ----- **DOESN'T UPDATES (Sometimes)**
     ---------------- **THIS IS WHERE QUERY STOPS AT TIMES** 
     ---------------- **SO THIS UPDATE IS NOT FIRED**    
     Update TaskDla   
     Set TaskStatusId = 1,        
     Comments = 'Set to In Progress by System'        
     Where TaskDLAId =@taskDlaIdSelected; 

 -- MOD #4 : log history of submission file update      
 insert into [dbo].[RequestHistory]        
  ([RequestId],[StatusId],[Description],[StatusChangeBy],[StatusChangeDate],[UpdateType])        
 values        
  (@RequestId, 1, 'SubmissionFileId #' + cast(@submissionid as varchar) + ' set to In Progress', 'usp_SaveTaskSME', Getdate(), 'In Progress')           
    
    Select 1      
      End  
    Else        
      Begin        
       Select 2        
      End
```

The SubmissionFileData table has an index on another column which is an identity.

Things I have tried so far :

I have created a NonClustered Index on
the column in where condition here which is **TaskDlaId**
I also checked the query plan to check and it says that the Number of Rows which the update reads is only 1 as shown below -

[image]

Can you guys suggest what else i can do here.

Comment: How do you "know" the `UPDATE` isn't being executed at all? If it isn't, this either implies that the definition of the procedure isn't what you expect, or you're not executing the procedure you think you are; perhaps you're connected to the wrong database or instance, or the procedure is being called without a schema and the `USER`'s default schema isn't `dbo` and thus you're calling a different procedure of the same name.

Comment: @Larnu if you look in the code, there are inserts made in history table, to track the updates in tables. When i look into the logs made in History then for the records in which the Update did not happen, i don't see the logs afte the Update. Only the inserts made in RequestHistory table before the Update are shown.

Comment: check ```@requestId``` is getting or not  form ```SubmissionFileData ``` table

Comment: That doesn't say the `UPDATE` was skipped, @Rishabh , it could mean there were no rows to `UPDATE`. Very different things.

Comment: @Larnu : I have added the full code now in procedure for you.

Comment: So none of the SQL from `---- Mod#3 -----` is executed, @Rishabh ? So the SQL after `-- MOD #4` is also not run? I would therefore suggest you aren't executing the procedure you *think* you are.

Comment: @Yogesh well requestId is being obtained from table correctly.

Comment: @Larnu : had that been the case then mod1 and mod2 would not have been executed and this is the only proc which has these logs....so this proc is getting run as always, it's just blows up at Mod3 and then no further execution takes place and that too happens in PROD environment

Comment: *"it's just blows up at Mod3"* So it generates an error? What is the error?

Comment: Your code should assume success and THROW an error when it does not work as expected. Some error handling would be good as would some formatting to help everyone read / understand your code. If you update a specific row (or rows - we don't know your schema) then you should lock it to prevent others from changing (or deleting) it. Locking will require a transaction - which I don't see. Significant improvements can be made here.

Comment: *"had that been the case then mod1 and mod2 would not have been executed"* Mod3 and 4 are *after* Mod1 and Mod2 in your definition.

Comment: @Larnu : we don't get the error by *blows up* i meant that it doesn't execute it further say like for 1 on every 1000 times it was called.

Comment: So, again, I stand by my statement: Seems you aren't executing the version of the proc you *think* you are, and the one you are only has code up to the statement after Mod2; thus Mod3 and Mdo4 aren't run because they don't exist in this *other* version.

Comment: @Larnu infact i don't have any access on PROD db to look and check the query analysis and unfortunately in DEV this problem never occurs

Comment: Then someone who has access to production needs to debug it, @Rishabh . Sounds like Production and Development aren't aligned, if I am honest (which would explain why the definitions aren't the same).

Comment: @Larnu: i just checked, the definitins are all same in both environment and this is the only procedure which perfomrs these updates.

Comment: @Larnu : intially i was thinking that may be due to n number of sessions trying to execute this same proc in PROD might be triggering this issue so i create an index on the key in where clause but even after doing so we still see1 records every now and then in which this update doesn't take place.

Comment: Then I go back to the point I made in my latter [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68740702/sql-server-update-query-inside-a-procedure-not-working-even-after-optimisation?noredirect=1#comment121484442_68740702), there are no rows to `UPDATE`. That, however, doesn't explain why the `INSERT` doesn't occur at mod4. Honestly, we don't have enough information here. The best you can do is spend the time creating a  [mre]; you'll likely find the problem when you do.

Comment: Do you have a index on TaskDLAId column of TaskDla table? I think timeout error could be raised when updating TaskDla table if no index exists. If multiple column Index contain TaskDLAId column, TaskDLAId column must be first in order.

Comment: @doctorgu: yes i did create the index on column TaskDla before posting here and i thought it will fix it but i didn't...but yes index is created for the column.

Comment: @SMor : yes, this is what i am also thinking about... to put Transactions block and throw some error via try catch as well. Since i don't have any means to view the query analysis in the PRD environment then these blocks will be my only friend here.

Comment: @SMor : But don't you think Transactions will further put some more locking ??

Comment: @Larnu: The table *RequestHistory* which is above the Update query ( which is causin the problem btw) has like 27 million records, so does the Insert which is happening in this *RequestHistory* table can cause any disruption ?